# Explain code in Kinect SDK

Tags: kinect

I am working with **Kinect** and reading example from `DepthWithColor-D3D`, has some code but i don't understand yet.

```
// loop over each row and column of the color
for (LONG y = 0; y < m_colorHeight; ++y)
{
    LONG* pDest = (LONG*)((BYTE*)msT.pData + msT.RowPitch * y);
    for (LONG x = 0; x < m_colorWidth; ++x)
    {
        // calculate index into depth array
        int depthIndex = x/m_colorToDepthDivisor + y/m_colorToDepthDivisor * m_depthWidth;

        // retrieve the depth to color mapping for the current depth pixel
        LONG colorInDepthX = m_colorCoordinates[depthIndex * 2];
        LONG colorInDepthY = m_colorCoordinates[depthIndex * 2 + 1];
```

How to calculate the value of `colorInDepthX` and `colorInDepthY` as above code?

Comment: this code appears to be obtaining those values from some data structure, not requiring you to calculate anything. What are you confused about?

Comment: hi, i mean that why differ between colorInDepthX and colorInDepthY is "+1"?

Answer (score 0):

`colorInDepthX` and `colorInDepthY` is a mapping between the depth and color images so that they will align.  Because the Kinect's cameras are slightly offset from each other their field of views are not lined up perfectly.

`m_colorCoordinates` is defined at the top of the file as such:

```
m_colorCoordinates = new LONG[m_depthWidth*m_depthHeight*2];
```

This is a single dimension array representing a 2-dimensional image, it is populated just above the code block you post in your question:

```
// Get of x, y coordinates for color in depth space
// This will allow us to later compensate for the differences in location, angle, etc between the depth and color cameras
m_pNuiSensor->NuiImageGetColorPixelCoordinateFrameFromDepthPixelFrameAtResolution(
    cColorResolution,
    cDepthResolution,
    m_depthWidth*m_depthHeight,
    m_depthD16,
    m_depthWidth*m_depthHeight*2,
    m_colorCoordinates
    );
```

As described in the comment, this is running an calculation provided by the SDK to map the color and depth coordinates onto each other.  The result is placed inside of `m_colorCoordinates`.

`colorInDepthX` and `colorInDepthY` are simply values within the `m_colorCoordinates` array that are being acted upon in the current cycle of the loop.  They are not "calculated", per se, but just point to what already exists in `m_colorCoordinates`.

The function that handles the mapping between color and depth images is explained in the Kinect SDK at MSDN.  Here is a direct link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj663856.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i don't understand why:colorInDepthX = m_colorCoordinates[depthIndex * 2]; and colorInDepthY= m_colorCoordinates[depthIndex * 2 + 1], why differ between colorInDepthX and colorInDepthY is "+1"?

Comment: `m_colorCoordinates` is a 1-dimensional array representing a 2-dimensional data set.  It is placing the data for a given `x` and a given `y` coordinate next to each other in the array -- so any given point within the 2-dimensional image is represented in the 1-dimensional array as `x=n` and `y=n+1`.

Comment: hi, I fully understood. thanks you so much, Evil Closet Monkey!

Comment: Hi @Evil Closet Monkey, when i look some codes, like this: 'index = ((colorY * width) + colorX) * 4'. What is **4**? Regards!